# Same CSS for two tables but the cell widths are different

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a strange problem. I created two tables with same code but they render different style.

Here is my code

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr {
  border: 1px black dotted;
}
table tr td {
  border-right: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Table1
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div>
  Table2
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">a1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">a12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">a1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">a12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6b9eL0xk/

Please help me understand why the column widths are different.

Comment: As you didn't set a width to the table's cells, their size depends on its content, which is different, hence layout is too

Comment: Please check it: https://jsfiddle.net/a0kxt17y/4/ .Border of "tr" still isn't correct. @LGSon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the cells a width, like below, as when not, they will adjust their size according to the remainder (space left) in each cell.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
width:100%;
}

table, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr {
    border: 1px black dotted;
}
table tr td {
    border-right : solid 1px black;
    width: 25%;                         /*  added property  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  Table1
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> 12 </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div>
  Table2
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">a1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> a12 </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">a1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">a12</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant column size , it's because your text length

Change it like Table 1

If you want fix this , add width for your column